# Android - Get height of single line from TextView with few lines

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with few lines and i need to calculate just the height of one line, not the total TextView height.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextView`'s height divided by `TextView`'s rows should give you the height of one row hence every line has the same height with one text size.